# Applying smooth scroll when clicking an anchor link (Pure Javascript)

Tags: javascript

i'm writing the code, when the anchor link is clicked jump directcly to the specific section within the page.

here i want to make sure that the page is smoothly scrolled either up or down according to the specific section clicked through the anchor link.

although there is so many answers on stack overflow discussed the same issue but i just want to test my skills by writing my own code.

i finally notice that my code is not working and it throw many errors

i hope there is a good and better solution to improve my code

Any help will be appreciated

```js
function smoothScroll(){
let x = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
for(let i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){
x[i].onclick=function(){
let  target = this.hash;
  target.scrollIntoView({
  behavior:'smooth',
  alignToTop:true,
  block:'start'
      });
     }
   }
}
smoothScroll();
```

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.1,shrink-to-fit=no">
     <link type="text/css" href="/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>smoothScroll</title>
         </head>
         <body>
          <div class="nav">
          <a href="#section1" style="color:#fff;">Link1</a>
           <a href="#section2" style="color:#fff;padding-left:3rem;">Link2</a>
            <a href="#section3" style="color:#fff;padding-left:3rem;">Link3</a>
           </div>
            <div id="section1"onclick="myFunction();" style="margin:10px auto; width:400px;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
printing and typesetting industry.
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
 when an unknown printer took a galley 
 of type and scrambled it to make a 
 type specimen book. 
</div>
    <div id="section2" style="margin:100px auto; width:400px;">
It has survived not only five centuries, 
but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
remaining essentially unchanged. 
It was popularised in the 1960s 
with the release of Letraset sheets 
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus 
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
  <div id="section3" style="margin:100px auto; width:400px;">
Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, 
Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
 It has roots in a piece of classical 
 Latin literature from 45 BC,
 making it over 2000 years old. 
</div>

        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: This is not duplicate. The OP has a specific approach and is not looking for different ways to do this. Just want to fix the error with proper reason and if possible improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function smoothScroll(){
let x = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
for(let i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){
x[i].addEventListener("click" ,function(){
  
  this.scrollIntoView({
  behavior:'smooth',
  alignToTop:true,
  block:'start'
      });
     }
  )
   }
}
smoothScroll();
```

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.1,shrink-to-fit=no">
     <link type="text/css" href="/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>smoothScroll</title>
         </head>
         <body>
          <div class="nav">
          <a href="#section1" style="color:#fff;">Link1</a>
           <a href="#section2" style="color:#fff;padding-left:3rem;">Link2</a>
            <a href="#section3" style="color:#fff;padding-left:3rem;">Link3</a>
           </div>
            <div id="section1"onclick="myFunction();" style="margin:10px auto; width:400px;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
printing and typesetting industry.
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
 when an unknown printer took a galley 
 of type and scrambled it to make a 
 type specimen book. 
</div>
    <div id="section2" style="margin:100px auto; width:400px;">
It has survived not only five centuries, 
but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
remaining essentially unchanged. 
It was popularised in the 1960s 
with the release of Letraset sheets 
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus 
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
  <div id="section3" style="margin:100px auto; width:400px;">
Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, 
Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
 It has roots in a piece of classical 
 Latin literature from 45 BC,
 making it over 2000 years old. 
</div>

        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: when to use this script to my codes above?? if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    )

Comment: what's the role of this line `if ( location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname ) ` @JustinWilliam as you mentioned in your comment ?

Comment: @ sazzad location.pathname or window.location.pathname  returns the domain name of the webhost  .....window.location.hostname  or window.location.hostname  returns the domain name of the web host . on our code above   location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')  we're replacing the first forward slash (/) in the pathname for the current location and comparing it to the link that's been clicked.     example we've  /scrollTutorials/anchor and we use location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')  to get scrollTutorials/anchor

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error, the issue is with the element reference for the `scrollIntoView`.

You are providing the `hash` value as element reference which is incorrect. You need to pass the element after selecting it with the hash value.

`let target = document.querySelector(this.hash);`
`target.scrollIntoView()`

```
function smoothScroll(){
    let x = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
    for(let i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){
      x[i].onclick=function(){
      let target = document.querySelector(this.hash);
      target.scrollIntoView({
      behavior:'smooth',
      alignToTop:true,
      block:'start'
          });
         }
       }
    }
    smoothScroll();
```

`scrollIntoView()` is cross-browser compatible.

Reference: https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t23

**DEMO:**

```js
function smoothScroll(){
let x = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
for(let i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){
x[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let target = document.querySelector(this.hash);
  target.scrollIntoView({
  behavior:'smooth',
  alignToTop:true,
  block:'start'
      });
     });
   };
}
smoothScroll();
```

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.1,shrink-to-fit=no">
     <link type="text/css" href="/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>smoothScroll</title>
         </head>
         <body>
          <div class="nav">
          <a href="#section1" style="color:#fff;">Link1</a>
           <a href="#section2" style="color:#fff;padding-left:3rem;">Link2</a>
            <a href="#section3" style="color:#fff;padding-left:3rem;">Link3</a>
           </div>
            <div id="section1"onclick="myFunction();" style="margin:10px auto; width:400px;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
printing and typesetting industry.
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
 when an unknown printer took a galley 
 of type and scrambled it to make a 
 type specimen book. 
</div>
    <div id="section2" style="margin:100px auto; width:400px;">
It has survived not only five centuries, 
but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
remaining essentially unchanged. 
It was popularised in the 1960s 
with the release of Letraset sheets 
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus 
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
  <div id="section3" style="margin:100px auto; width:400px;">
Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, 
Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
 It has roots in a piece of classical 
 Latin literature from 45 BC,
 making it over 2000 years old. 
</div>

        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: The above didn't work? It should work and is tested with your code as well. There is no room for improvement though. Your code is fine.

Comment: @JustinWilliam Sorry, please check now. The issue was with the element reference from my side as well. I have edited my answer. You can also run the code snippet and test.

Comment: @ ashiish.me yah now it is working thank you bro!!! is  it a cross browser ??

Comment: @JustinWilliam Yes, it is. I have attached the reference link.

Comment: how can we remove  http://localhost/scrollTutorials/anchor  and remain with http://localhost/scrollTutorials

Comment: You want to remove the anchor from the browser address bar but scroll as expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219960/discussion-between-justin-william-and-ashiish-me).